# How can I use Kukai wallet on alphanet?

Tags: wallets

How do I use [Kukai wallet](https://kukai.app/) on alphanet?

I would really like to test some things out before going on mainnet. Especially the "Send to Multiple Destinations" feature.

Suggestions for other wallets with "Send to Multiple Destinations" feature are also very welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always follow the instructions on [Github](https://github.com/kukai-wallet/kukai) to build an Electron application from the source code. In that case you want to modify [constants.ts](https://github.com/kukai-wallet/kukai/blob/master/src/app/constants.ts) to use the alphanet instead of the mainnet. For security reasons this is hard-coded and can not be modified during runtime.

To make life easier you can now also access the alphanet version at https://alphanet.kukai.app.